# I cannot use MacBook Pro 2017's built-in keyboard and touchpad on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, live-usb, macbook

I am a MacBook user and I tried to run Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacBook Pro 2017 15-inch yesterday. Ubuntu Live USB can boot normally, but the keyboard and touchpad are completely unusable, so nothing can be done except shutting down.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

For the MacBook Pro 2016 to 2017 you will need an external USB keyboard and Wifi to get work with Linux: 
https://nixaid.com/linux-on-macbookpro/

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  It is good practice here to summarize the important points of the link you refer to, ensuring your answer remains valid even if the link disappears.